# close modal using escape key using jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have a modal popup that closes by pressing the Esp key on the keyboard. But again if I click on the button for modal it is not appearing until I refresh the screen ( I have to refresh the screen every time to appear the modal after hitting the ESP key). Please help me where I'm going wrong below is my code. Thank you

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.modal-toggle').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.modal').toggleClass('visible');
      });     
    })

    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
      var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
      if (code == 27) $(".modal").hide();
    });
```

```css
.modal{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10000;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
 .wrap_model {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
    top: 37px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -256px;
    background-color: #fff;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
      border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
    height: 124px;
    width: 320px;
    text-align: center;}
    
.modal.visible {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

.modal.visible {
  transform: translateY(0);
  opacity: 1;
}   
.footer{
    position: absolute;
    top: 77%;
    left: 50%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="modalContent">
  <button class="modal-toggle">Click me!</button>
 </div>
 <div class="modal">
     <div class="modal-toggle"></div>
     <div class="wrap_model">   
       <div class="footer">
        <button class="">CONFIRM</button>
        <button class="">CANCEL</button>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to use `$(".modal").hide();`you will have to :

- call `$(".modal").show();` on click on the button
- start your modal with `display:none` instead of `visibility: hidden`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.modal-toggle').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".modal").show();
  });
})

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if (code == 27) $(".modal").hide();
});
```

```css
.modal {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10000;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrap_model {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  top: 37px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -256px;
  background-color: #fff;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
  height: 124px;
  width: 320px;
  text-align: center;
}

.modal.visible {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

.modal.visible {
  transform: translateY(0);
  opacity: 1;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 77%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modalContent">
  <button class="modal-toggle">Click me!</button>
</div>
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-toggle"></div>
  <div class="wrap_model">
    <div class="footer">
      <button class="">CONFIRM</button>
      <button class="">CANCEL</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

or you can simply call toggle class instead of `$(".modal").hide();`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.modal-toggle').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.modal').toggleClass('visible');
  });
})

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if (code == 27) $('.modal').toggleClass('visible');
});
```

```css
.modal {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10000;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrap_model {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  top: 37px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -256px;
  background-color: #fff;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
  height: 124px;
  width: 320px;
  text-align: center;
}

.modal.visible {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

.modal.visible {
  transform: translateY(0);
  opacity: 1;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 77%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modalContent">
  <button class="modal-toggle">Click me!</button>
</div>
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-toggle"></div>
  <div class="wrap_model">
    <div class="footer">
      <button class="">CONFIRM</button>
      <button class="">CANCEL</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the on click event, you use `$('.modal').toggleClass('visible');`, but for the on escape button click, you are using .hide();

This solution works for me:

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.modal-toggle').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.modal').toggleClass('visible');
      });     
    })

    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
      var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
      if (code == 27) $('.modal').toggleClass('visible');
    }); 
</script>
```

Note: You would need to add an event handler for your cancel button click too.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the above code didn't work for me.

Comment: Did you definitely remove the $(".modal").hide()?

Answer (score 0):

The `hide()` JQuery method doesn't change the visibility but the display rule. You have to chose between toggle visibility or display (`show()` method with JQuery).

Answer (score 0):

You're using two different approaches to show/hide the modal.  You show it like this:

```
$('.modal').toggleClass('visible')
```

But hide it like this:

```
$(".modal").hide()
```

Those are two *very different things*.  According to [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/hide/):

> This is roughly equivalent to calling `.css( "display", "none" )`

You're basically stacking two different kinds of "hiding".  The modal still has the `visible` class, you've just changed its `display` to no longer be shown.

If you want to use the `visible` class, be consistent with that approach.  You can hide it with this:

```
$('.modal').toggleClass('visible')
```

Though this would also re-show it by simply pressing ESC on the page, which *probably* isn't want you want.  So hide it more explicitly with this:

```
$('.modal').removeClass('visible')
```